# Basic tox setup to test a package

Tags: python, setuptools, tox

I am trying to use `tox` to test a package I am writing and I cannot get it to work. My `setup.cfg` contains the following section:

```
[tox]
envlist = py36,py37,py36-black

[testenv]
deps =
    pytest
commands =
    pytest tests

[testenv:py36-black]
deps =
    black
    flake8
    flake8-black
    mypy
commands =
    black --check --diff setup.py mypackage tests
    flake8 mypackage tests
    mypy mypackage tests
```

I have a `setup.py` file to install my module, and if I run `pip install -e .`, everything works well and I can use the module normally.

Now, if I run:

```
tox -e py36,py37,py36-black -p all
```

The tests for `py36-black` succeed but `pytest` fails because it cannot find `mypackage`. Basically, it seems that `tox` does not install my own package in the virtual environments it creates.

Do I  have to run `pip` manually in the `commands` under `[testenv]`? Or did I do something wrong in my `setup.cfg`?

---

Here is my `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

with open("README.md", "r") as fp:
    long_description = fp.read()

install_requires = ["numpy", "scipy"]

test_requires = ["pytest", "mypy", "black", "flake8", "flake8-black"]

setup(
    name="mypackage",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="Holt",
    install_requires=install_requires,
    test_requires=test_requires,
    extras_require={"test": test_requires},
    py_modules=["mypackage"],
    long_description=long_description,
    license="MIT",
    python_requires=">=3.5",
)
```

My directory structure is:

```
mypackage/
    __init__.py
    ...
tests/
    test_mypackage.py
setup.py
setup.cfg
```

Full logs from `tox --recreate -e py36 -p all`:

```
action: py36, msg: parallel py36
cwd: /home/holt/Dev/python/mypackage
cmd: /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tox/__main__.py --recreate -e py36 -p all --installpkg .tox/.tmp/package/1/mypackage-0.0.1.zip
py36 recreate: /home/holt/Dev/python/mypackage/.tox/py36
py36 installdeps: pytest
WARNING: Discarding $PYTHONPATH from environment, to override specify PYTHONPATH in 'passenv' in your configuration.
py36 inst: /home/holt/Dev/python/mypackage/.tox/.tmp/package/2/mypackage-0.0.1.zip
WARNING: Discarding $PYTHONPATH from environment, to override specify PYTHONPATH in 'passenv' in your configuration.
py36 installed: You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.,You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.,attrs==19.3.0,importlib-metadata==0.23,mypackage==0.0.1,more-itertools==7.2.0,numpy==1.17.4,packaging==19.2,pluggy==0.13.1,py==1.8.0,pyparsing==2.4.5,pytest==5.3.1,scipy==1.3.3,six==1.13.0,wcwidth==0.1.7,zipp==0.6.0
py36 run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='789851852'
py36 run-test: commands[0] | pytest tests
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.7, pytest-5.3.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.1
cachedir: .tox/py36/.pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/holt/Dev/python/mypackage
collected 0 items / 1 error

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
____________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_mypackage.py _____________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/holt/Dev/python/mypackage/tests/test_mypackage.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests/test_mypackage.py:5: in <module>
    import mypackage
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypackage'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=============================== 1 error in 0.10s ===============================
ERROR: InvocationError for command /home/holt/Dev/python/mypackage/.tox/py36/bin/pytest tests (exited with code 2)
```

Comment: No you shouldn't have to. From where are you launching tests? Please provide the content of your `setup.py` and launch command line.

Comment: Do you have a `requirement.txt` file?

Comment: We need more information: your directory structure, `setup.py`, logs from `tox`.

Comment: @Tim I don't have a `requirement.txt` file. I've updated the question with `setup.py`, directory structure and `tox` logs.

Comment: @phd I've updated the question with `setup.py`, directory structure and `tox` logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug in your `setup.py`:

```
py_modules=["mypackage"],
```

`py_modules` installs **modules**, that is `setup.py` expects to find `mypackage.py`. Not finding it it doesn't package anything into sdist.

You need to install `mypackage` as a **package**. Replace the line with

```
packages=["mypackage"],
```

or even with

```
packages=find_packages(),
```

importing `find_packages`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
```